# pandas Third Column answer is based on column 1 and column 2

Tags: python, pandas

First - I have tried reviewing similar posts, but I am still not getting it.

I have data with corporate codes that I have to reclassify. First thing, I created a new column -['corp_reclassed'].

I populate that column with the use of the map function and a dictionary.

Most of the original corporate numbers do not change thus I have nans in the new column (see below).

```
corp_number corp_reclassed
100                 nan
110                 nan
120                 160 
130                 nan
150                 170
```

I want to create a final column where if ['corp_reclased'] = nan then ['corp_number] is populate by the ['corp_number'] . If not, then populate['corp_reclassed'].

I have tried many ways, but I keep running into problems.  For instance, this is my lastest try:

```
df['final_number'] = df.['corp_number'].where(df.['gem_reclassed'] = isnull, eq['gem_reclassed'])
```

Please help.

FYI- I am using pandas 0.19.2. I get upgrade because of restrictions at work.

Comment: Can you share some data entries ?

Comment: `df['final_num'] = np.where(df['corp_reclassed'].isna(), df['corp_number'], df['corp_reclassed'])`?

Comment: There's a dedicated function for this usecase: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a `fillna`?

```
df['final_number'] = df['corp_reclassed'].fillna(df['corp_number'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df.loc[df['gem_reclassed']= pd.np.nan, 'final_number'] = df['corp_reclassed']
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: also I think the code in the indexer is wrong: you're using the assignment (`=`) operator rather than equality test (`==`)...